# Rails - add elements to array using text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I want to do something that should be really simple: use an input text field to add elements to an array. As simple as it may seem, I'm kind of stuck...

Each User has a (single) Profile. Each Profile contains a text-field 'entertainment' that is serialized as an array in the ProfilesController.

I got as far as updating the attribute with a fixed text by using the following:

**method in the ProfilesController**

```
def update_entertainment
   @user = User.find_by(params[:id])
   @profile = @user.profile
   @user.profile.update(entertainment: ["the usual suspects"])
   redirect_to profile_path(current_user, tab:"entertainment")
end
```

**profile_params in the ProfilesController**

```
def profile_params
   params.require(:profile).permit(:gender, :date_of_birth, :zip_code, :city, :state, :country, :marital_status, :entertainment )
end
```

**the form**

```
<div class="form-group">  
    <%= text_field :entertainment, :class => 'form-control' %>
    <%= button_to("+", :action => :update_entertainment, :method => :put, :remote => true) %>
</div>
```

However, whatever I've tried (and that is a lot), I cannot manage to PUSH (not just update) the input of a text-field to the array. For now adding one element at a time will do. What I really want to do is give users the opportunity to ADD elements to the array.

I'm using Rails 4.0.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was in using `button_to` instead of usual form.

[Normal form](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) instead of [`button_to`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

With the help of @D.K. and @anushka I was able to solve the issue. I changed the changed the line

```
@profile.entertainment << params[:entertainment]
```

in the ProfilesController to

```
@profile.entertainment << params[:entertainment]
```

and changed the form to this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= form_tag(:action => :update_entertainment, :method=>'post', :multipart => true, :class => 'form-control') do %>
    <div class="input-group">
      <%= text_field_tag :entertainment, nil, :class => 'form-control form-group', :placeholder => 'add interests' %>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
      <%= submit_tag '+', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
      </span>
   </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```